# Definition of ordered pair and intuition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are many definitions of ordered pairs where the most common is probably the definition of Kuratowski $$(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}.$$ This definition does a phenomenal job at capturing what we expect to be true about ordered pairs, namely that $$(x,y)=(x',y') \iff x=x' \wedge y=y'.$$ However, I am unsure whether this captures the intuition of what an ordered pair is and whether it has to capture this intuition. Intuitively an ordered pair (from left to right) is a collection of two objects where the elements are ordered (from left to right). Thus, if we capture collections as sets, one would expect that ordered pairs are sets which contain two elements, namely the first (or left) and the second (the right). Obviously the definition above is a set, but I don't think its intuitive to choose the exact elements of the set to be the ones that define this notion of ordered pairs. However, something like $\{x,y\}$ obviously fails. Thus I am unsure if what I would like to have is even possible, or whether what I want to have is the "wrong" thing to expect, really. However, I think that the intuition about ordered pairs is a good justification/intuition for the definition of a function as it is done in set theory, which is why I was hoping to find one that is intuitive in this way. Are there any solutions to this? Is my perspective on this wrong perhaps?

**Edit:** I fear that I give the encoding too much meaning. This probably comes from a platonistic viewpoint, meaning that if there exists some sort of notion of ordered pair and we encode "our notion" of ordered pair, they should hopefully coincide. However, we dont have a guarantee for that and I don't know if this is a good approach. Especially, could there be something going wrong if they don't coincide as long as they capture the important properties? I don't know...

Comment: As you agree, the encoding does it job in the sense that it captures the necessary properties. Whether or not it's intuitive is, in this context, more or less a matter of opinion. E.g., in my opinion the definition of a function is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: However, in another sense, this does capture the intuition of an ordered pair *precisely because it has to property you highlight*.

Comment: Note also that the definition encapsulates $(x,y)≠(y,x)$.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName As I have formulated in the edit, I fear that I give too much meaning to the actual encoding. If you have anything to say on this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: We also have the concept of "ordered set". Using that you could say naively: an ordered pair where $x$ comes first is a set $\{x,y\}$ accompanied with an order $\leq$ on $\{x,y\}$ such that $x\leq y$. But taking a closer look at $\leq$ we find that this is by definition a set of *ordered pairs*. So we are blocked by self-reference. If we want to define orders then a definition of ordered pair must come before that.

Answer (score 1):

"I am unsure whether this captures the intuition of what an ordered pair *is* ..." But do we have any such intuition? If we have an intuition here (if that's quite the right word), isn't it an intuition of  what an ordered pair *does*?

Arguably, what we need here is the general idea of a *pairing scheme*, in something like the following sense:

> A scheme for pairing objects $G$ with objects $G'$ provides
>
> 1. some pair-objects $O$ (which can be any suitable objects, and may or may not be already among  $G$ or $G'$);
> 2. a binary pairing function which we can notate '$\langle\ ,\ \rangle$' which sends $x$ from among $G$ and $x'$ from among $G'$ to a pair-object $\langle x, x'\rangle$ among $O$ (with every pair-object being some such $\langle x, x'\rangle$);
> 3. two unpairing functions which send a pair-object $\langle x, x'\rangle$ to $x$ and $x'$ respectively.

Note, it is immediate from this definition that the pairing function sends distinct pairs $x, x'$ and $y, y'$  to distinct pair-objects $\langle x, x'\rangle$ and $\langle y, y'\rangle$.

The angle-brackets might remind you of the  standard set-theoretic construction of ordered pairs. But  all we need to do the work of a pairing scheme are *some* objects to 'code' for pairs together with interlocking pairing and unpairing functions. And NB: for objects $O$ to serve as pairs is not a matter of their intrinsic nature, but of the role they play in a pairing scheme.

For example, if the objects $G$ and $G'$ are in both
cases natural numbers, then we could perfectly well take the pair-object $\langle m,n\rangle$ to be the number $2^m3^n$, with the obvious pairing and  unpairing functions. OK, in this case, the pair objects in the pairing scheme are not 'ordered' nor do they have the objects they pair as 'members'. But of course, that's exactly how it is with Kuratowski pairs too!

But there's more to be said along these lines. You could, for example, take a look at Chapter 10 of *Beginning Category Theory* (downloadable from https://www.logicmatters.net/categories/) which is called 'Pairs and products, pre-categorially' and presupposes no category theory, and whose final section also mentions a possible alternative approach to pairing/unpairing as purely logical operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would argue that the intuition behind an ordered pair of two objects is that it is a concept of a collection of two objects that are grouped in a way where the order of the grouping matters. Naively, one can imagine pairs of coins on a table where I predefine the ordering by saying that the order is given from left to right. This could then be generalized to more abstract objects, namely being a pair of those with some predefined notion of an ordering. An ordered pair of numbers would then be a collection of numbers (whatever they are) where the ordering matters.

Comment: I don't know if such an approach would make sense, but I appreciate any further comments on this.

Comment: "An ordered pair of numbers would then be a collection of numbers (whatever they are) where the ordering matters". But what does this "ordering" mean, over and above that we can recover a first number and a second number from the "collection"? I.e. what makes for a "collection where the ordering matters" over and above being a pair-object in a pairing scheme of the kind described?